# Lithium-Ion - leave at full or charge and discharge

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, lithium-polymer

I am getting a laptop soon, and am wondering if I should leave the Li-ion battery at full during use, or have it charge and discharge within a range of, say, 40-80%. The goal here is maximum battery in-service life.

Comment: If your storing it for a long period of time, keep it at 50% otherwise reduce the number of charging cycles

Comment: Vague requirements in question cannot be generalized unless actual data exists for each LiPo pack brand unxder same conditions as supplier quality changes all these results.  Even **in-service life** is undefined for power % consumption vs % AC/(AC+DC) use or ambient temperature each which affects test results (-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the current draw of the laptop. See the graph below with varying SoC (State of Charge) values. If you draw lots of current, then lifetime is reduced. However, total energy units may actually be higher.

> Case 1: 75–65% SoC offers longest cycle life but delivers only 90,000 energy units (EU). Utilizes 10% of battery.
>
> Case 2: 75–25% SoC has 3,000 cycles (to 90% capacity) and delivers 150,000 EU. Utilizes 50% of battery. (EV battery, new.)
>
> Case 3: 85–25% SoC has 2,000 cycles. Delivers 120,000 EU. Uses 60% of battery.
>
> Case 4: 100–25% SoC; long runtime with 75% use of battery. Has short life. (Mobile phone, drone, etc.)

[image]

Source: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most research collected by Battery University. (BU) But often put faith in the smart charge apps offered by the top brands as I know they do a lot of research on battery profiles and
Algorithms for extending life EU’s. (Panasonic, Samsung, Lenovo)

Of course keeping loaded processes
to a minimum and display intensity as well will also extend life and charge interval. One can tell if their CPU is warm by the fan speed. Although the battery pack is far away, with fresh air, the base of laptop should never be blocked which raises the ambient temperature.

But user awareness and
Maintenance is recommended as the weakest cell accelerates aging the fastest and becomes the weak link at end of life from imbalance due to cell over/under charge.

As is true for iOS and Windows the latest and greatest OS major release is also consuming more power. But I have many other reasons not to use Win 10, so I customize my Win 7,8 builds to lean yet powerful.

Comment: Barely relevant answer, if at all. But has tips for battery longevity so it avoids a down vote from me. Also, it misses out on linux, which will be what I use.

Comment: A graph on L-ion batteries may be relevant to Li-Polymer packs  but innacurate comparison.  Better to generalize than to give an innaccurate answer to a vague question. Not all laptops are same or use same technology or even same brand batteries, which is very relevant!